# Delete duplicated rows by modified_date - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql

I've got some duplicated rows on a table called ja_jobs:

To find those duplicated data, I'm running this Query:

```
select * from ja_jobs WHERE clientid = 33731 AND creatortype = 'legacyrec' AND deleted = false AND time_job IS NOT NULL AND (time_job,recurrenceid) IN (
select time_job,recurrenceid FROM ja_jobs WHERE clientid = 33731 GROUP BY time_job,recurrenceid HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

The query finds duplicated rows by time_job and recurrenceid.

On the following example:

[image]

You can see that the jobs are duplicated, but we have three versions of it (Just look on the modified_date column)

I need to delete the new jobs and only keep the OLDEST one.

```
DELETE from ja_jobs WHERE id IN (14754912,14792799);
```

How can I do that?
How can I select all the newest jobs and just delete them?

Here what I've got so far:

```
select min(id) over (partition by time_job,recurrenceid,time_arrival order by created_date) as min_id into junk.test_table FROM ja_jobs
WHERE clientid = 33731 AND creatortype = 'legacyrec' AND deleted = false AND (time_job,recurrenceid) IN (
select time_job,recurrenceid FROM ja_jobs WHERE clientid = 33731 GROUP BY time_job,recurrenceid HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

But on the junk.test_table table I got duplicated "min_id"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing grouping criteria twice while creating junk_test, first in the GROUP BY subselect by having fewer conditions in the WHERE, and then in the PARTITION BY by having one extra partitioning field (`time arrival`).

If you can assume that older ids are older jobs, then you can identify your duplicates by joining grouped table with itself, like this:

```
SELECT jd.dup_group_no, j.id=jd.id AS to_keep, j.id INTO junk.test_table
FROM (
  SELECT time_job, recurrenceid, client, creatortype, deleted, MIN(id) AS id, row_number() over () AS dup_group_no
  FROM ja_jobs
  WHERE clientid = 33731 AND creatortype = 'legacyrec' AND deleted = false
  GROUP BY time_job, recurrenceid, client, creatortype, deleted
  HAVING count(*) > 1
  ) jd
JOIN ja_jobs j USING (time_job, recurrenceid, clientid, creatortype, deleted);
```

If there is no guaranteed correlation between older ids and older jobs by creation time, the query is trickier:

```
SELECT jm.dup_group_no, j.id=jd.id AS to_keep, j.id INTO junk.test_table
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (jd.time_job, jd.recurrenceid, jd.clientid, jd.creatortype, jd.deleted) jd.time_job, jd.recurrenceid, jd.clientid, jd.creatortype, jd.deleted, jd.id, row_number() over () AS dup_group_no
  FROM (
    SELECT time_job, recurrenceid, client, creatortype, deleted
    FROM ja_jobs
    WHERE clientid = 33731 AND creatortype = 'legacyrec' AND deleted = false
    GROUP BY time_job, recurrenceid, client, creatortype, deleted
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) jd
  JOIN ja_jobs jm USING (time_job, recurrenceid, clientid, creatortype, deleted)
  ORDER BY jd.time_job, jd.recurrenceid, jd.clientid, jd.creatortype, jd.deleted, jd.created_date, jd.id
  ) jm
JOIN ja_jobs j USING (time_job, recurrenceid, clientid, creatortype, deleted);
```